# Convergences realated to variance

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,..$ be independent random variables satisfying

$\sum_{n>=1} \frac{Var(X_n)}{n^2} <\infty$

Prove that: $\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{n=1}^{k} Var(X_n) \longrightarrow 0$ as k tends to $\infty$

Can anybody give me some hints to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing special going on, it is just a simple inequality about finite sums and the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum \frac {a_n} {n^{2}} <\infty$. Then $\frac 1 {k^{2}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} a_n \to 0$: let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $N$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac {a_n} {n^{2}} <\epsilon$. Now $\frac 1 {k^{2}} \sum\limits_{n=N}^{k} a_n \leq  \sum \limits_{n=N}^{k}  \frac {a_n} {n^{2}} <\epsilon$ for all $k>N$. Now observe that $\frac 1 {k^{2}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n \to 0$, so we are done.